# Using ES6 and let/const with export / import and Karma/webpack - export at the top

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, karma-mocha, karma-webpack

```
export { test };

const test = (str) => {
    return str;
};
```

```
import { test } from './func';

describe('func', () => {
    describe('func', () => {
        it('should return the same string', () => {
            expect(test('hello world')).to.equal('hello world');
        });
    });
});
```

test-function is undefined because of hoisting, I suppose.
Because if I do:

```
const test = (str) => {
    return str;
};

export { test };
```

The test works.

But, I would like to keep my exports in the top of the file for easy reference.

Any way to achieve that?

My karma.conf.js:

```
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
const fileGlob = 'src/**/*.test.js';

module.exports = (config) => {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
        files: [fileGlob],
        preprocessors: {
            [fileGlob]: ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: webpackConfig,
        webpackMiddleware: {noInfo: true},
        reporters: ['progress', 'mocha'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['Firefox'],
        singleRun: true,
        concurrency: Infinity,
    });
};
```

And relevant parts of package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",

    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",

    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",

    "chai": "^4.1.1",
    "mocha": "^3.5.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",

    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",

  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES module import reflects the state of module export. Even though `const` decaration is not hoisted, it is in temporal dead zone when `export { test }` is evaluated, but when the module is imported export already reflects `test` actual value.

The problem likely results from incorrect behaviour caused by module transpilation. Babel [doesn't implement module exports correctly](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzjYBneBfA3AKBwYwgDt1k14BeOACnSgEo4KA-RHODuKYGAVyiJw6ubEA&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D), this results in `undefined` export.

As it can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KTLUihy9THfthKQnpsS0?p=preview) (available in browsers that support ES modules, i.e. latest Chrome), module export works as intended natively.

TypeScript [handles exports as intended](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20%7B%20test%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20%28str%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20str%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B), too.

To make code compatible with existing implementations, it should be:

```
export const test = (str) => {
    return str;
};
```

Or:

```
const test = (str) => {
    return str;
};

export { test };
```

Both are conventional ways to do exports, particularly because of this issue. Exports at the end of the module conform to coding habits that result from the use of CommonJS modules.

Comment: Yeah definitely a Babel bug.